# Webpack Bundle Analyzer on post-optimized output

Tags: webpack, webpack-bundle-analyzer

Webpack Bundle Analyzer (and awesome tools like https://github.com/statoscope/statoscope) seem to operate on dependency graphs before DCE & tree-shaking optimizations have occurred.

Are there webpack community tools that exist that emit bundle analytics on the final bundle/chunks/entrypoints versus simply the entry dependency graphs? I want output that shows stats on the final code in bundle, vs the modules participating in the bundle.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I need to check myself. Seems like the `parsed` section actually may be correct: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-bundle-analyzer#parsed